# После нажатия кнопки не выполняет переход на другую кнопку,что делать?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram

После нажатия Алгебра, должен перейти на Таблицу умножения ,чего она и не делает, не пойму где ошибка, кидаю кусок кода:

```
        if message.text == 'Поддержать разработку':
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, mess1)
        if message.text =='Быстрый поиск:':
                markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard = True, row_width=2)
                algebra = types.KeyboardButton('Алгебра')
                geoma = types.KeyboardButton('Геометрия♾️')
                nazadbistr = types.KeyboardButton('Вернуться в главное меню⬅️')
                markup.add(algebra, geoma, nazadbistr)
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Быстрый поиск:', parse_mode = 'html', reply_markup = markup)
        if message.text =='Алгебра:':
            markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard = True, row_width=2)
            tableumnoz = types.KeyboardButton('Таблица умножения')
            markup.add(tableumnoz)
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Алгебра:', parse_mode = 'html', reply_markup = markup)
```

Comment: Зачем вы постоянно указываете parse_mode если никак не используете разметку?

Comment: в будущем буду менять,это наброски пока что

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if message.text =='Алгебра:':
```

Замените на

```
if message.text =='Алгебра':
```

Comment: мне очень жаль что я вас тревожу по таким мелочам,спасибо большое)